# This operation is not supported in the WCF client

Tags: c#, wcf, wcftestclient

Why I start my wcf service at localhost:53776/MyService.svc I get this error in the wcf test client.

This operation is not supported in the WCF client:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILSKTicketService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task UploadLDTTickets(LDTTicketUploadDTO[] tickets);
}
```

Why is this type not supported?

How else can I test my Service endpoint?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should ask yourself if you really need to return a Task as return type, since there are other complications implied.

Second (and mainly what you asked), beside using the standard WCFTestClient, you can create a separate application, add a Service Reference to your end point ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx ) and then using the generated client to test your calls ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx ) with more flexibility than what is offered from WCFTestClient.

Comment: Ditto Task return type. How is a server going to communicate back that the task has finished? Tasks are usually generated on the client proxy interface and are used to wait until the call itself has returned.

Comment: Probably he wanted to implement the async/await pattern because this Upload I can infer from the method name might be a lengthy operation, but he should do that on the client side of his architecture if that's his only requirement.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer right these are separated processes how could the client know.

Comment: The Upload is an insert into 10 sql tables via EF.

Comment: @Pascal: A task represents a promise to do some work. How will your separate process notify the original process when the work is complete?This would require a duplex WCF contract.

Comment: When I remove the Task stuff on server side and rename also my method (without async at the end) and do a refresh service with the test client I still see UploadLDTTicketsASYNC in the test client? What is going on?

Comment: You have created an Async method using async wait pattern it s only logical to have an async version of your method

Comment: The default WCF project, always creates an async instance of all your methods on its own. But you will notice that invoking those will throw a not implemented exception (unless you explicitly implement those).